# React createElement does not add children of type string when mutiple children are part of inner html

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React.createElement(...) to dynamically generate a basic react site using a json file.

The json file is array of JSON objects which represent an element (and its children). The JSON object for an individual element looks like this.

```
{
    "id": "e960f0ad-b2c5-4b0b-9ae0-0f6dd19ca27d",
    "render": true,
    "component": "small",
    "styles":[],
    "classes":[],
    "children": [
        "&copy;2017",
        {
            "id": "04fa3b1a-2fdd-4e55-9492-870d681187a4",
            "render": true,
            "component": "strong",
            "styles":[],
            "classes":[],
            "children": [
                "Awesome Company"
            ]
        },
        ", All Rights Reserved"
    ]
}
```

this object "should" ideally generate the following html code

```
<small>©2017 <strong>Awesome Company</strong>, All Rights Reserved</small>
```

I have created react components to render these html elements for example

Small.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Small = ({ id, className, style, children }) => {
    return (
        <small id={id} style={style} className={className}>
            {children}
        </small>
    )
}

export default Small
```

Similarly I have created jsx for other html elements like anchor tag, div, footer, button etc

There is renderer.js which is called by App.js to render each component in the json file

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from "../components/Button";
import Input from "../components/Input";
import Header from "../components/header/Header";
import Footer from "../components/footer/Footer";
import Div from "../components/containers/Div";
import Article from "../components/containers/article/Article";
import Fragment from "../components/containers/Fragment";
import Anchor from "../components/Anchor";
import Nav from "../components/Nav";
import Heading1 from "../components/typography/Heading1";
import Strong from "../components/typography/Strong";
import Small from "../components/typography/Small";

const componentMap = {
    button: Button,
    input: Input,
    header: Header,
    footer: Footer,
    div: Div,
    article: Article,
    fragment: Fragment,
    a: Anchor,
    nav: Nav,
    h1: Heading1,
    small: Small,
    strong: Strong
};

const generateComponentStyles = (styles) => {
    let mappedStyles = {};
    styles.forEach(style => {
        mappedStyles[style.name] = style.value;
    });
    return mappedStyles;
}

function renderer(config) {
    if (typeof componentMap[config.component] !== "undefined") {

        //creating children array for this element
        let elementChildren = [];
        if(config.children && config.children.length > 0) {
            for (let index = 0; index < config.children.length; index++) {
                const child = config.children[index];
                if(typeof config.children === "string") {
                    elementChildren.push(child);
                } else {
                    elementChildren.push(renderer(child));
                }
            }
        }

        return React.createElement(
            componentMap[config.component],
            {
                id: config.id,
                key: config.id,
                className: config.classes ? config.classes : null,
                style: config.styles ? generateComponentStyles(config.styles) : null
            },
            elementChildren
        );
    }
}
  
export default renderer;
```

The problem is even when the `<small>` tag is generated with the inner html of `<strong>` but it skips inserting the pure text within the small and strong tags, so the elements come out as empty.

This is what is generated on the site

```
<small id="e960f0ad-b2c5-4b0b-9ae0-0f6dd19ca27d" class=""><strong id="04fa3b1a-2fdd-4e55-9492-870d681187a4" class=""></strong></small>
```

As you can see it did not insert the text.

If I however do not supply an array to the "children" attribute but just give a simple string then it shows up. This same thing happens on an anchor tag.

Based on this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement the createElement takes the third param as array of children.

I even tried to wrap my text in an empty fragment to pass it but it did not work either.

How do I insert a plain text within the inner html of an anchor, small, strong etc when there are other children to be inserted as well?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple one, because as far as I understood it mainly works with the exemption of the string nodes.

Please check the condition:

```
typeof config.children === "string"
```

should be

```
typeof child === "string"
```